# Discrepancies between profile and /reputation pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I went to my profile in search of an answer I wrote some while ago, I tried to recall the date via reputation gain at the said date.

In the process I ran across a date in which it was indicated I had +190 reputation, and at least one answer did not contribute any reputation (that is, I capped out and those votes were without gain).

Wondering about this date, I went to check https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation in which the same date shows +200 with four post-capping votes.

Both list agree that I only received votes on four particular answers, however one of them is claiming I should have +200 and one says that I only have +190.

Which one is the accurate one, and how such discrepancy could occur? I should also report that my reputation is correct, that is no need for a recalc - which makes me suspect it may be a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reputation in your profile doesn't change e.g. when a question with your answer in it is deleted. There are a few ways this can get out of sync with your "real" reputation value. Another problem are retracted upvotes after you already hit the daily reputation cap.

The `/reputation` page is more accurate, as far as I understand it, but it still doesn't necessarily show you the correct reputation value.

The only way to get a current, accurate reputation value is to trigger a reputation recalc, everything else can be out of sync.

Comment: I don't recall anything being deleted but a recalc indeed solved this issue (while the amount of reputation was correct, it corrected this discrepancy).